# Onclick of sifr font - Color of sifr font should change

Tags: sifr

Im using sifr for the heading of horizontal tabs. When the tab is active it must be blue color and the other tab must be in black color.So how do I switch the tab colors when the tabs are clicked. Please explain

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the replace sIFR CSS:

```
'.sIFR-root {color: #000000; }  a { color: #000000;} a:active{ color: #0000FF;}'
```

Then for your tabs assuming your sIFR selector is p:

```
<p><a href="#">YOUR TAB</a></p>
```

I assume that the normal state of your tab is black... You can use a:hover for hover, too. For example, if your tab needs to be green when the cursor is hovering over the tab:

```
a:hover{color:#00FF00}
```

You might consider using Cufon instead if your text isn't justified... Cufon rocks and I'd use it for everything if only it could be justified... It's very fast and not Flash dependent.

```
http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/
```